# Displaying word documents, excel sheet, power point in browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there is any way to displaying world document,excel sheet and power point in browser with out downloading.

Comment: yes... called google docs

Comment: Or use something like [Print2Flash](http://print2flash.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are going to use php for this, so you can try checking some libraries such as [PHPWord by Microsoft](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to only display the document content, it is possible to do using some scripting language such as php. Basically office 2007+ formats are zipped XML documents with changed extension. Make a simple word 2007+ document, save it and change extension from .docx to .zip, than you can extract it and see what it's made of. You can find a lot of details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx). Now displaying content may be a little tricky. As mentioned, there are libraries out there to handle this, but how will they handle the documents, I am not really sure. Most of them are abandoned, PHPword is in beta since 2011.

There are some indications that Apache is working on cloud version of Open office, but there is no release date yet. Once done, you will have a full featured office suite web app.

If you feel really creative you could use cron job (or scheduled task if you like Windows) to open a document, take a screenshot and basically make .jpg or .png version of the document (works fine with short documents, longer ones may be problematic), displaying it in a browser without much complication. It is also possible to schedule export to .pdf - all browsers do have Adobe PDF plugins.

To sum up, using php for parsing simple documents should be fine, but getting complex docs to display properly, may be much more difficult task and possibly not worth your time. I would go for cron export to pdf, to preserve most if not all of the document's structure.